# how to set imageview src?

Tags: android

I have an image view and a string src. I want to set the imageview source to the **string** src that I  have, but am unable to do so beacuse the method expects an int:

```
imgview.setImageResource(int);
```

Since this method takes an int how can I accomplish my goal of using a string?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Each image has a resource-number, which is an integer. Pass this number to "setImageResource" and you should be ok.

Check this link for further information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

e.g.:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Answer (score 41):

To set image cource in imageview you can use any of the following ways. First confirm your image is present in which format.

If you have image in the form of bitmap then use

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

If you have image in the form of drawable then use

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

If you have image in your resource example if image is present in drawable folder then use

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

If you have path of image then use

```
imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("pathofimage"));
```

Comment: Got really excited about .setImageURI but it doesn't appear to work for http based URIs.  System.out reads "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://...". :(

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is probably this:

```
ImageView myImageView;
myImageView = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
String src = "imageFileName"

int drawableId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(src, "drawable", context.getPackageName())
popupImageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

Let me know if this was helpful :)